# How to resolve UndefVarError: <MODULENAME> in julia?

Tags: package, julia

julia> using MbedTLS

precompiled properly and made available.

Now, invoking

Julia> using WebSockets

throws UnderVarError: MbedTLS not defined, though both resides in the same folder.

Where it is looking for the module/package? Please guide me in resolving the UndefVarError:<MODULENAME>

Comment: Are you trying to add these packages without an Internet connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the package `MbedTLS.jl` have not been `add`ed.

If you have already *cloned* `MbedTLS.jl` into your computer, then use `add /local/path/to/MbedTLS.jl/` in Pkg mode. The folder name should be `MbedTLS.jl`. You can enter in Pkg mode typing `]` in the REPL.

If you have *not* cloned but just downloaded `MbedTLS.jl` and you do not want to clone it, then just initialize a git repository in the `MbedTLS.jl` folder, add all the files (ignoring the ones in `.gitignore`) and commit the changes with the following,

```
cd /local/path/to/MbedTLS.jl/
git init
git add .    
git commit -m "add all the files"
```

Then in Julia Pkg mode, `add /local/path/to/MbedTLS.jl/` to add the `MbedTLS.jl` package. The folder name again should be `MbedTLS.jl`.

The same goes for `WebSockets.jl`.

If you plan to make changes to these packages, you can edit the files in the local git repository and commit them or go into develop mode with for example `develop --local MbedTLS` to work on another copy easily.

You might want to read the `Pkg` documentation in Julia manual [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Pkg/index.html) or the more detailed Pkg manual [here](https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/).